# How to compress a file before saving on the disk?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to compress a file before saving physically on the disk.

I tried using compress and decompress methods (MSDN sample code) but all methods require a file which is already physically stored on the disk.

Comment: do you want save file without name?

Comment: Can't you save file on disk and compress it and save it again, and delete the uncompressed version? Also which MSDN sample you are referring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to open the file as a `Stream` and wrap it with a compression API like `GZipStream`.

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(theFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate) {
  using (var stream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
    // Write to the `stream` here and the result will be compressed
  }
}
```

Comment: @NIleshLanke then use `GZipStream` with the `CompressionMode.Decompress` option

Comment: The DeflateStream and GZipStream classes are best used on uncompressed sources of data. If the source data is already compressed, using these classes may actually increase the size of the stream.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

You can use the `GZipStream` class not only with a fileName. It is possible to compress a `Stream`.

> **GZipStream Class** Provides methods and properties used to compress and decompress streams.

#### Sample

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sw = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
        System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
// now you can save the file to disc
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the GZipStream class? It's stream based, so you shouldn't need an on-disk file to use this class.

Which kind of data are you trying to compress?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MemoryStream` and `GZipStream`.

File is an array of bytes so you can try following code according to http://www.dotnetperls.com/compress :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] text = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new string('X', 10000));
            byte[] compress = Compress(text);

            Console.WriteLine("Compressed");
            foreach (var b in compress)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ", b);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
        {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
                }
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```